# How to create a new activity in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

**I'm making my first game and use for that LibGDX.
And before starting the game, I want to show the user a menu, for example, play, rating, settings.
How can I create this activity?
So far, I have a banal thought to create an activity and register in the manifest (making it start)**

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

**I did so and nothing worked**

Comment: Start thinking LibGDX way. If you want to maintain compatibility trough all supported platforms you can not use platform specific features.

Comment: It's definitely possible. You would create a second Activity that has the launcher intent filter, and remove the intent filter from the Game's Activity. But I recommend implementing everything in the game itself. You can use libGDX screens. This allows you to test everything on desktop without having to keep installing it on a device, which is slower. And you can port to desktop or iOS much easier later if you decide to.

Answer (score 4):

Hello in libGdx you don't use activity because this is an android particularity (except for launching the ligGdx application)
Instead different solution can be use in fonction of your need :

1. Screen: Screen can be use to separate part of your application not displayed in the same time for example : Main menu is a the screen and your game is another screen)
2. Stage: Are different part of your application displayed in the same time (in the screen). (In a shooter you will have the stage with 3D world and the stage with the ui (bullet counter, life viewer...))

I think with this 2 tools you will be able to do what you want.

I advise you to see [LibGdx official tuto](https://libgdx.com/dev/simple_game_extended/)
Who explain a lot of things (especially Screen) and totally answer your question